What does (call) actually do?
I was looking for a way to set the errorlevel in a batch file, and found that I can use the call command. For example:
@echo off

echo    errorlevel = 0 - space after call
        (call )
        echo %errorlevel%

echo    errorlevel = 1 - no space after call
        (call)
        echo %errorlevel%

pause

That’s a neat trick, but what, exactly does (call) or (call ) do?

IMHO you should not use a "strange trick" in order to set the errorlevel. You should use a simpler command like verify, that is the method suggested by MS to set the errorlevel: verify -> 0, verify other -> 1. See Table 2 at this answer for further details.

@Aacini point taken, but I was curious about the call command, and what’s happening here.

As said in a couple comments below: nobody knows... :(

The behaviour of (call) and (call;) was explained by Dave Benham in this DosTips topic as far back as Feb, 2013.

call calls another batch file or a subroutine.
In your example (call ) with a space calls nothing and terminates with errorlevel 0, since the command is executed well. Just an empty call in brackets.
In (call) you have a "file not found" error (Errorlevel is 1), since CMD tries to start the command or file "call)", that doesn't exist.
EDIT:
CALL without any space sets the errorlevel to 1 as well. No error message appears.
Thanks to @Aacini for the additional explanation

So, the second one attempts to run a non-existing command called call). That makes sense. Why the opening parentheses?

not sure if I get your question right. parantheses are being used for code-blocks (ex. in an if-block). So the opening one is interpreted as a block start.

I see. (call) is a block with a single empty call command. (call ) starts a block, but the call  is misinterpreted.

Not quite right. "no such command or file" gives us an errorlevel of 9009, so the errorlevel 1 is generated by the call command itself. How? I guess the developer could answer that.

The call command alone (just the four letters) sets the errorlevel to 1. If you add at least one space after the "call", the command sets the errorlevel to 0 (although no command is executed). Why? Nobody knows... :( Because spaces are difficult to see in posted code, those who  discovered this "trick" use parentheses to clearly mark the space.
